# Java Kafka Consumer store state in memory?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I'm having a usecase where I need to "batch process" events data for customers.

Every piece of event data would have a customerId.

In my application layer (java), I will need to batch up all the events per customer id and then apply my business logic. My business logic needs all the events per customer to be available. Basically, I'm grouping by customerId before I can do anything with it.

**Approach:**
Ingest all the events to a Kafka Topic **with partition key as "customerId"**. Therefore the events belonging to a specific customer always goes to the same consumer. In the consumer, I can gather the events in memory (perhaps using a simple expiry map or so) and do a batch process. In this approach, my entire batch is transient and stored in the application memory.

**Caveats:**
When Kafka partitions rebalancing happens (for whatever reasons) and when different partitions are re-assigned to different consumers, the data becomes inconsistent. Not sure if there's any way to overcome that.

I'm wondering what is a practical approach for such "batch" use cases? Is Kafka-Streams the right candidate for this? But this is not an infinite stream. The batch data set clearly has a start and end. End event is used as a trigger to perform the business logic.

Comment: If the data clearly has an end, why consume it from a Kafka topic? If you want to build a materialized view, yes, can use a Global KTable, but using Kafka Connect to sink the topic to a database would also work

Comment: The reason why DB approach doesn't fit for our use case is this component essentially is a microservice driven by messages and has no awareness (and no extra overhead and cost of a database) of the data sources (except kafka of course). It's sort of a Data-In-Data-Out utility.

Comment: Sure, but Kafka isn't permanently persistent, so have you turned off retention or are always using compaction? There's nothing preventing microservices from using databases in addition to / in place of a message queue

Comment: Absolutely agree. But for this service (only), having a DB is what I'm trying to avoid purely because this is sort of a utility service - all it does is pure data transformation and doesn't need to hold any state therefore doesn't need a DB.

Comment: "grouping" anything **is** a stateful process. You're maintaining historical data, then aggregating it based on some attributes. You don't need an external database, you could use sqlite, or h2, or rocksdb like Kafka Streams does

Answer (score 0):

The events will be **ordered** per customerId, but without a StickyAssignor in the consumer instances, they will not <strike>"go to"</strike> be consumed by the same consumer, especially in the event of replaces in a distributed environment

If you have some data in a compact topic that acts as your raw events, and consuming them all into some cache will build up your materialized view, then that's what Kafka Streams does with changelog topics, yes. You can also build this logic on your own with a plain consumer like the Confluent Schema Registry does with its `_schemas` topic and multiple internal Hashmaps